# Naming conventions to use 2 foreign keys to the same table in Fluent NHibernate using Sharp Lite Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

Here is my issue.

I have a customer table and an address table. The customer table has two foreign keys to the address table. ShippingAddressFK and BillingAddressFK

Normally I'd just have AddressFK if it was just one foreign key. But since it's two I'm not sure how to go about it.

I saw this:
[Fluent Nhibernate AutoMapping -- 2 foreign keys to same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423377/fluent-nhibernate-automapping-2-foreign-keys-to-same-table)

But I'm not sure how to translate that to the Sharp Lite Architecture override .cs file.

In the MyStore example this was the closest I could find:

```
public class OrderOverride : IOverride
    {
        public void Override(ModelMapper mapper) {
            mapper.Class<Order>(map => map.Property(x => x.OrderStatus, 
                status => {
                    status.Type<OrderStatusCustomType>();
                    status.Column("OrderStatusTypeFk");
                }));
        }
    }
```

I notice they are similar I'm just not sure how to change the solution above to fit this sort of override class in the Sharp Lite Architecture

Answer (score 0):

No access to visual studio so haven't tried this out, consider psuedo code based on the code you pasted and the code in the other question you linked to:

```
public class CustomerOverride : IOverride
{
    public void Override(ModelMapper mapper) {
        mapper.Class<Customer>(map => map.Property(x => x.BillingAddress, 
            address => {
                address.Type<Address>();
                address.Column("BillingAddressFk");
            }));
        mapper.Class<Customer>(map => map.Property(x => x.ShippingAddress, 
            address => {
                address.Type<Address>();
                address.Column("ShippingAddressFk");
            }));
    }
}
```

I just had a look at [Order override in SharpLite](https://github.com/codai/Sharp-Lite/blob/master/Example/MyStore/app/MyStore.NHibernateProvider/Overrides/OrderOverride.cs) and this isn't fluent nhibernate, it is nhibernate code mapping which I have never used. that might not be the correct way to define multiple property overrides but hopefully the code above will work. if not change the fluentnhibernate tag to nhibernate and some1 who knows more about it should be able to help.

Comment: That was my first instinct as well. But it's not how it's done. When I do it that way I get the following exception: "Expected type implementing IUserType, ICompositeUserType or IType.
Parameter name: persistentType" 

So I'm thinking this might be something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The example you are referring to is for mapping one of your properties to a custom type, like an Enum.

You need to map your *relationship* to the multiple addresses, and give it a different column name than what your conventions would.

```
public void Override(ModelMapper mapper)
{
    mapper.Class<Customer>(map =>
                           map.ManyToOne(
                               x => x.BillingAddress,
                               x => x.Column("BillingAddressFk")));

    mapper.Class<Customer>(map =>
                           map.ManyToOne(
                               x => x.ShippingAddress,
                               x => x.Column("ShippingAddressFk")));
}
```

Notice the `ManyToOne` instead of `Property`.